# Terraform not saving state of ECS Cluster containerInsights setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is my template:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "doesntmatter" {
  name = var.doesntmatter_name

  capacity_providers = ["FARGATE", "FARGATE_SPOT"]
  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }

  tags = var.tags
}
```

When I run it. It properly creates cluster and sets containerInsights to enabled.
[image]

But when I **run terrafrom again. It wants to change this property as if it wasn't set before.**
It doesn't matter how many times I run it. It still thinks it needs to change it every deployment.

[image]

Additionally, the terraform state show *resName* does show that this setting is saved in state file.

Comment: Where do those tags come from? Your code does not create any tags.

Comment: I would try upgrading to the latest version of the AWS Terraform provider if you haven't already.

Comment: I have newest aws terraform provider.

Comment: I can confirm we have also started to notice this behavior recently, it appeared roughly 3/4 days ago

Comment: @AlexanderFortin Did you have any luck find ANY info about it? I searched interned and didn't find a single issue similar to this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug that is resolved with v3.57.0 of the Terraform AWS Provider (released yesterday).

> Amazon ECS is making a change to the ECS Describe-Clusters API. Previously, the response to a successful ECS Describe-Clusters API request included the cluster settings by default. This behavior was incorrect since, as documented here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-clusters.html), cluster settings is an optional field that s    hould only be included when explicitly requested by the customer. With the change, ECS will no longer surface the cluster settings field in response to the Describe-Clusters API by default. Customers can continue to use the --include SETTINGS flag with the Describe-Clusters API to receive the cluster settings.

Tracking bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20684